# Using Python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Python dict. I'm trying to do a check with n if statement that payload contains "token"

```
{'payload': {'token': '3u4td7393493d9304'}, 'type': 'send'}
```

Below is the python code

```
if message['payload'] == 'token':
    print("GOT IT");
    print(message)
elif message['payload']['type'] == 'timedout':
    print("TIMEDOUT!")
elif message['payload'] == 'locked':
    print("LOCKED!")
    done.set()
```

The current if statement for token is wrong. What is the proper way of checking if payload has "token" inside it?

Comment: `type` isn't in the `payload` dict, it's in the `message` dict. Shouldn't it be `message['type'] == 'timedout'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether a dictionary `d` contains key `k`, use `k in d`:

```
message = {'payload': {'token': '3u4td7393493d9304'}, 'type': 'send'}
        # {'payload': {'locked': 'lockId'}, 'type': 'send'}

if 'token' in message['payload']:
    print("GOT IT");
    print(message)
    print(f"token: {message['payload']['token']}")
elif message['type'] == 'timedout':
    print("TIMEDOUT!")
elif 'locked' in message['payload']:
    print("LOCKED!")
    print(f"locked value: {message['payload']['locked']}")
    # done.set()
```

Since you have nested dictionaries, `message['payload']` is itself a dictionary, therefore to check whether it has key `'token'`, you have to use `'token' in message['payload']`.

I've also added an example that demonstrates how to access the value that corresponds to the key 'token'.

Side note: this `if-else` does not seem to be exhaustive, and it lacks the default case. Maybe you should approach it a bit more systematically, and first make sure that you deal with every possible `type` of the message, and then for each `type` deal with each kind of payload.

Answer (score 1):

The way i understand your question is you want to find whether or not 'token' exist in payload, regardless of the token value?

If yes, simple in array would suffice:

```
dc = {'payload': {'token': '3u4td7393493d9304'}, 'type': 'send'}

'token' in dc['payload'] # this would result in True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function which return True or False , now whenever you want to check pass value to that function and check :

```
def check_token(data_):
    if 'token' in data_['payload']:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now back to your code , you can simply check by passing value to this function :

```
if check_token(data)==True:
    print("GOT IT")
```

output:

```
GOT IT
```